# Why aren't some spid values showing up in sys.dm_exec_requests?

Tags: sql-server, dmv

I am executing the following dmv query against SQL Server 2014 to find all activity on a server and any blocking activities:

```
SELECT Distinct
   ...
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests er
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) st
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ses ON ses.session_id = er.session_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections con ON con.session_id = ses.session_id
WHERE st.text IS NOT NULL And DB_Name(er.database_id) IN ('Vincent', 'Vincent_Audit')
ORDER BY BlockingSessionId Desc, SessionId
```

Sample results of this query are as follows:

[image]

You can see that session 120 is blocked by 112 and 112 is blocked by 69. However, process 69 doesn't appear because it doesn't exist in sys.dm_exec_requests.

So, the following query returns no results:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
Where session_id = 69
```

Anyone know why this would be?

Comment: What happens if you take out `st.text IS NOT NULL`? Even better, why not use [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com)?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - The problem is that spid 69 doesn't exist, at all, in sys.dm_exec_requests.

Comment: Also, you're filtering on the database name and blockers/blockees may have a different db context.

Comment: Guys, when I execute the following query, no results are returned:  SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
Where session_id = 69

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - Yes, I modified my post to better explain this.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - How can an spid represent a blocking process if it isn't an active request?

Comment: Sessions executing show up in sys.dm_exec_requests if they are ACTIVELY running when the command is run. This doesn't stop a batch from blocking another batch and then not do anything with it. Nothing wrong here imho.

Comment: [Pretty easily](https://pastebin.com/CUXsiXt5)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sessions can exist without an active request, but still block other sessions.

Consider if you have one window open in SSMS where you run this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Then in another window you run:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable;
```

The first session will be holding locks on `dbo.SomeTable`, without it showing up in `sys.dm_exec_requests`.  You *will* see the session in `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, and you'll be able to see the open transaction in `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions`.

I'd recommend Adam Machanic's [sp_WhoIsActive](https://whoisactive.com), however if you aren't allowed to download scripts to run against your server, you may consider something like the following code that can identify open transactions without an active request that are blocking other sessions:

```
/*
    This query shows sessions that are blocking other sessions, including sessions that are 
    not currently processing requests (for instance, they have an open, uncommitted transaction).

    By:  Hannah Vernon, 2017-03-20
*/
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; --reduce possible blocking by this query.

USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dm_tran_session_transactions') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #dm_tran_session_transactions;
SELECT *
INTO #dm_tran_session_transactions
FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dm_exec_connections') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #dm_exec_connections;
SELECT *
INTO #dm_exec_connections
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dm_os_waiting_tasks') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #dm_os_waiting_tasks;
SELECT *
INTO #dm_os_waiting_tasks
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dm_exec_sessions') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #dm_exec_sessions;
SELECT *
INTO #dm_exec_sessions
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dm_exec_requests') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #dm_exec_requests;
SELECT *
INTO #dm_exec_requests
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests;

;WITH IsolationLevels AS 
(
    SELECT v.*
    FROM (VALUES 
              (0, 'Unspecified')
            , (1, 'Read Uncomitted')
            , (2, 'Read Committed')
            , (3, 'Repeatable')
            , (4, 'Serializable')
            , (5, 'Snapshot')
        ) v(Level, Description)
)
, trans AS 
(
    SELECT dtst.session_id
        , blocking_sesion_id = 0
        , Type = 'Transaction'
        , QueryText = dest.text
    FROM #dm_tran_session_transactions dtst 
        LEFT JOIN #dm_exec_connections dec ON dtst.session_id = dec.session_id
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dec.most_recent_sql_handle) dest
)
, tasks AS 
(
    SELECT dowt.session_id
        , dowt.blocking_session_id
        , Type = 'Waiting Task'
        , QueryText = dest.text
    FROM #dm_os_waiting_tasks dowt
        LEFT JOIN #dm_exec_connections dec ON dowt.session_id = dec.session_id
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dec.most_recent_sql_handle) dest
    WHERE dowt.blocking_session_id IS NOT NULL
)
, requests AS 
(
SELECT des.session_id
    , der.blocking_session_id
    , Type = 'Session Request'
    , QueryText = dest.text
FROM #dm_exec_sessions des
    INNER JOIN #dm_exec_requests der ON des.session_id = der.session_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(der.sql_handle) dest
WHERE der.blocking_session_id IS NOT NULL
    AND der.blocking_session_id > 0 
)
, Agg AS (
    SELECT SessionID = tr.session_id
        , ItemType = tr.Type
        , CountOfBlockedSessions = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests r WHERE r.blocking_session_id = tr.session_id)
        , BlockedBySessionID = tr.blocking_sesion_id
        , QueryText = tr.QueryText
    FROM trans tr
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM requests r
        WHERE r.blocking_session_id = tr.session_id
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ta.session_id
        , ta.Type
        , CountOfBlockedSessions = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests r WHERE r.blocking_session_id = ta.session_id)
        , BlockedBySessionID = ta.blocking_session_id
        , ta.QueryText
    FROM tasks ta
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rq.session_id
        , rq.Type
        , CountOfBlockedSessions =  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests r WHERE r.blocking_session_id = rq.session_id)
        , BlockedBySessionID = rq.blocking_session_id
        , rq.QueryText
    FROM requests rq
)
SELECT agg.SessionID
    , ItemType = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + COALESCE(a.ItemType, '') FROM agg a WHERE a.SessionID = agg.SessionID ORDER BY a.ItemType FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')
    , agg.BlockedBySessionID
    , agg.CountOfBlockedSessions
    , agg.QueryText
    , des.host_name
    , des.login_name
    , des.is_user_process
    , des.program_name
    , des.status
    , TransactionIsolationLevel = il.Description
FROM agg 
    LEFT JOIN #dm_exec_sessions des ON agg.SessionID = des.session_id
    LEFT JOIN IsolationLevels il ON des.transaction_isolation_level = il.Level
GROUP BY agg.SessionID
    , agg.BlockedBySessionID
    , agg.CountOfBlockedSessions
    , agg.QueryText
    , des.host_name
    , des.login_name
    , des.is_user_process
    , des.program_name
    , des.status
    , il.Description
ORDER BY 
    agg.BlockedBySessionID
    , agg.CountOfBlockedSessions
    , agg.SessionID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually turned out to be very educational. The reason spid 69 wasn't appearing in sys.dm_exec_requests was because sys.dm_exec_requests only shows actively running processes as Sean Gallardy pointed out. So, I executed sp_who and 69 did appear as a suspended process. An insert operation was being performed by the spid 69 and it was waiting on a resources to be freed. Therefore, it was suspended and not appearing in sys.dm_exec_requests.

Answer (score 0):

This simple query helped me to find tasks with open transactions, running longer than 30 minutes, that were not in sys.dm_exec_requests.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions t
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON t.session_id = s.session_id
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, s.last_request_end_time, GETDATE()) >= 30
```

Comment: The sys.dm_exec_sessions DMV also has an open_transaction_count column you can use to identify sessions with open transactions (Available SQL 2012 onwards).
I recently improved the monitoring in DBA Dash for sleeping sessions with open transactions if you are interested:
https://dbadash.com/blog/whats-new-in-2.46.0/
It's a free & open-source monitoring tool.